# Adding float numbers to Decimal numbers

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
var weightSum: Float = 3.14159
let weightPerPortionGrams: Decimal =  0.999999
weightSum = weightSum + (weightPerPortionGrams)
```

The numbers are examples.

I get an error:

> Binary operator '+ =' can not be applied to type 'Float' and 'Decimal'.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and work with only `Double` as your type for decimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variables `weightSum` and `weightPerPortionGrams` have different types. Luckily you can convert these variables in Swift.

So, to make this work, you should convert the type of `weightPerPortionGrams` to the one of `weightSum`, so both variables become the same type:

```
weightSum = weightSum + NSDecimalNumber(decimal: weightPerPortionGrams).floatValue
```

Note that `Decimal` might not handle the floating points quite well.

You can also do an extra cast, to make sure that we are using the methods of `NSDecimalNumber` and not of `NSNumber`:

```
let double = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: weightPerPortionGrams).doubleValue
weightSum = weightSum + Float(double)
```

Comment: I have error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(Decimal)'

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `Decimal` to a float, you can either do this:

```
weightSum += Float(truncating: weightPerPortionGrams as NSNumber)
```

or this:

```
weightSum += (weightPerPortionGrams as NSNumber).floatValue
```

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Does it not? It does on my machine. Are you using Swift 4? What is the error message? Which code snippet are you referring to?

Comment: I tried to run it on 4.1.2 http://online.swiftplayground.run/, error is `cannot convert value of type 'Decimal' to type 'NSNumber' in coercion`

Comment: Interesting! I'm using Xcode 9.3.1 so Swift 4.1.1. I guess that's why there are different results. @GiovanniTerlingen

Comment: Should work fine, `Decimal` can be bridged to `NSDecimalNumber` which is `NSNumber` subclass

Comment: @mag_zbc So it's the problem of  online.swiftplayground.run?

Comment: I did some slightly different approach to make it work on http://online.swiftplayground.run, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swift needs both variables to be of the same type to make use of the "+" operator, so you would need to either convert your `Decimal` to type `Float` or the other way around before summing them:

```
weightPerPortionGramsFloat = (weightPerPortionGrams as NSNumber).floatValue
```

or

```
weightSumDecimal = (weightSum as NSNumber).decimalValue
```

Comment: _Swift needs both variables to be of the same type to make use of the "+" operator_ - no, it doesn't

Comment: It doesn't? I though all arithmetic operators in swift needed the operands to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings!

```
    func + (left: Float, right: Decimal) -> Float {
        return left + Float(right.description)!
    }

    var weightSum: Float = 3.14159
    let weightPerPortionGrams: Decimal =  0.999999

    weightSum = weightSum + weightPerPortionGrams

    print(weightSum)
    // prints 4.141589
```

Hope it helps!